Grouping data and reassembling rows as columns
I have a table of times phone calls were made to people. If someone didn't answer, an attempt is made to ring them again (and again if needs be) at another time. Each attempt to call is listed in the same column so the 'person' column has repeated values. Something like this:



Person
Time of Call
Answer




1
12:00
No answer


2
12:12
No answer


3
12:19
Answer


2
18:10
No answer


1
13:00
Answer


2
19:12
Answer



I want to split the data so that there is one row per person with all the times calls were made, like this:



Person
First Call
First Answer
Second Call
Second Answer
Third Call
Third Answer




1
12:00
No answer
13:00
Answer




2
12:12
No answer
18:10
No answer
19:12
Answer


3
12:19
Answer








You can add a column that defines the id of each call within a person, and then use pivot_wider to generate columns based on these newly created id.
By default, it will put a NA if there is no corresponding call for the id.
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(person = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4))
df$call_time <- rnorm(nrow(df))
df %>%
  mutate(call_id = 1:n(), .by = person) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = person, names_from = call_id, names_prefix = "call_",
              values_from = call_time)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   person   call_1 call_2 call_3
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      1  1.26    -0.442  NA   
#> 2      2  0.356   NA      NA   
#> 3      3  0.241   NA      NA   
#> 4      4 -0.00412  0.926  -1.27

Created on 2024-07-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Though there already is an accepted answer I believe that the following shows that the OP needs an extra column and two pivot_wider calls.
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(toOrdinal)
})

df1 <- "Person  TimeofCall  Answer
1   12:00   'No answer'
2   12:12   'No answer'
3   12:19   Answer
2   18:10   'No answer'
1   13:00   Answer
2   19:12   Answer"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)

left_join(
  df1 %>%
    mutate(Call = paste(seq_along(Person) %>% toOrdinal(), "Call"), .by = Person) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = Person,
      names_from = Call,
      values_from = TimeofCall
    ),
  df1 %>%
    mutate(Call = paste(seq_along(Person) %>% toOrdinal(), "Time"), .by = Person) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = Person,
      names_from = Call,
      values_from = Answer
    ),
  by = join_by(Person)
) -> df_wide

i <- order(names(df_wide)[-1L]) + 1L
df_wide[c(1L, i)]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Person `1st Call` `1st Time` `2nd Call` `2nd Time` `3rd Call` `3rd Time`
#>    <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1      1 12:00      No answer  13:00      Answer     <NA>       <NA>      
#> 2      2 12:12      No answer  18:10      No answer  19:12      Answer    
#> 3      3 12:19      Answer     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
က
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'က' not found

Created on 2024-07-02 with reprex v2.1.0
